# Window.open don't work on android devices but work on browsers

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

When i click anything is running, i can see this error : plugin not installed but inappbrowser is intallled

In my config file: 

    
on ts file 
 window.open('https://geniusmuna.com/legal/', '_system');

Answer (score 0):

to browse the URL in android, you need to install [inAppBrowser](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/) Cordova plugin.

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
```

Comment: I have some problem when i am building ionic app with platform android..Build run successful but any native feature not working on android device. My app working verry well when i use chrome or devapp tool....With devapp tools alls components work verry well, but when i build the components not working....

Answer (score 0):

Try to call your methods after device is ready.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
  // Your code goes here
}, false);
```

[Refer source](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.3.0/cordova/inappbrowser/window.open.html)

Comment: I have some problem when i am building ionic app with platform android..Build run successful but any native feature not working on android device. My app working verry well when i use chrome or devapp tool....With devapp tools alls components work verry well, but when i build the components not working....

Comment: Not working is a result with which we can not diagnose the issue. Give us some other input like what kind of error message you are getting, ...

Comment: Try this link **https://medium.com/@coderonfleek/debugging-an-ionic-android-app-using-chrome-dev-tools-6e139b79e8d2**